# why would type_identity make a difference?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I know that a `lambda` object is not a `std::function` object, so I understand that this would not work:

```cpp
template <typename ...args_t>
void func(std::function<void(args_t...)> function_, args_t ...args){
    /// do something here
}

void test() {
    func([](int a){ }, 1);
}
```

but why would it work if I add a type_identity to wrap it?

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T>
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;

template <typename... args_t>
void func_wrapped(type_identity_t<std::function<void(args_t...)>> function_, 
                                  args_t ...args) {
    static_assert(std::is_same< std::function<void(args_t...)>,
                                 type_identity_t<std::function<void(args_t...)>>
                              >::value,
                  "different type");
    /// do something here
}

void test() {
    func_wrapped([](int a){ }, 1);
}
```

as far as I can see, these two look pretty much the same, and it even passed the `static_assert` which means they are the same to `std::is_same`.
but the compiler just doesn't think so. it told me that the in former code, lambda cannot match any function, while the latter one can.

`error: no matching function for call to ‘func(test()::<lambda(int)>, int)’`

so, my question is: why do they behave differently? what did type_identity do implicitly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The former code doesn't work because implicit conversion (from lambda to `std::function`) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which causes deduction of template parameter `args_t` on the 1st function parameter `function_` failing.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

The latter code works because of [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts):

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose **P** do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead *use* the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified.
>
> 1. The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope
>    resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a
>    qualified-id:

With the usage of `type_identity` the 1st function parameter `function_` is excluded from template argument deduction; and `args_t` could be deduced from the 2nd function parameter `args`, then it works fine.

BTW: Since C++20 we have [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity).